# Proof of lemma regarding independece of random vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

At my lectures for financial mathematics we stated the following lemma (proposition).

Let $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ be random vectors. If
$$
    \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(X_i)\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n f_i(Y_i)\right]
$$
holds for all bounded continuous functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$, then $\overline{X}$ and $\overline{Y}$ are identically distributed.

I would appreciate it if someone could suggest where I can find the proof, or even better, write the proof themseves. Im not well versed in probability so this is a result I believe I'm uncapable proving with my current knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace "bounded continuous" by any class that includes the indicator functions of closed non-empty intervals, the result is clear. Indeed, products of such functions include the indicator functions of a family of generating sets of the Borelian $\sigma$-algebra of $R^n$.

Then, you just have to notice that such indicator functions are increasing limits of positive continuous and bounded functions, and use Beppo Levi theorem to conclude.

Comment: Could you provide the source, where the proof is a bit detailed.

Comment: I don't know the source, I improvised the answer, sorry about that. Can I send you a picture of a detailed handwritten answer ? I don't have the time to type it right now.

Comment: Thank you for the  answer, but no need for the picture though, since you didnt prove the same proposition.

Comment: Well yes, this proves the same proposition, this is the point of the second part of my answer : if the conditions are met for continuous bounded functions, they will be met for my other class of functions by a limit argument.

Comment: @VlakecTomaz Here you go : https://i.imgur.com/iCjJ9LW.jpg and https://imgur.com/P8gweyW

Comment: Thank you very much!